# What is the following code will do after modifying it?

Tags: windows

The following commands will change the files information `gatherosstate.exe` file. From looking at the hex values I can interpret that there are `nop` (0x00). The file changed in windows terminal.
But what are more information can be extracted from it?

```
$bytes  = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:\Files\gatherosstate.exe")
$bytes[320] = 0xf8
$bytes[321] = 0xfb
$bytes[322] = 0x05
$bytes[324] = 0x03
$bytes[13672] = 0x25
$bytes[13674] = 0x73
$bytes[13676] = 0x3b
$bytes[13678] = 0x00
$bytes[13680] = 0x00
$bytes[13682] = 0x00
$bytes[13684] = 0x00
$bytes[32748] = 0xe9
$bytes[32749] = 0x9e
$bytes[32750] = 0x00
$bytes[32751] = 0x00
$bytes[32752] = 0x00
$bytes[32894] = 0x8b
$bytes[32895] = 0x44
$bytes[32897] = 0x64
$bytes[32898] = 0x85
$bytes[32899] = 0xc0
$bytes[32900] = 0x0f
$bytes[32901] = 0x85
$bytes[32902] = 0x1c
$bytes[32903] = 0x02
$bytes[32904] = 0x00
$bytes[32906] = 0xe9
$bytes[32907] = 0x3c
$bytes[32908] = 0x01
$bytes[32909] = 0x00
$bytes[32910] = 0x00
$bytes[32911] = 0x85
$bytes[32912] = 0xdb
$bytes[32913] = 0x75
$bytes[32914] = 0xeb
$bytes[32915] = 0xe9
$bytes[32916] = 0x69
$bytes[32917] = 0xff
$bytes[32918] = 0xff
$bytes[32919] = 0xff
$bytes[33094] = 0xe9
$bytes[33095] = 0x80
$bytes[33096] = 0x00
$bytes[33097] = 0x00
$bytes[33098] = 0x00
$bytes[33449] = 0x64
$bytes[33576] = 0x8d
$bytes[33577] = 0x54
$bytes[33579] = 0x24
$bytes[33580] = 0xe9
$bytes[33581] = 0x55
$bytes[33582] = 0x01
$bytes[33583] = 0x00
$bytes[33584] = 0x00
$bytes[33978] = 0xc3
$bytes[34189] = 0x59
$bytes[34190] = 0xeb
$bytes[34191] = 0x28
$bytes[34238] = 0xe9
$bytes[34239] = 0x4f
$bytes[34240] = 0x00
$bytes[34241] = 0x00
$bytes[34242] = 0x00
$bytes[34346] = 0x24
$bytes[34376] = 0xeb
$bytes[34377] = 0x63
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("C:\Files\gatherosstatemodified.exe", $bytes)
```

Comment: This is missing some important items.  Which operating system and processor?  What research have you done so far?  See https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. I concur, this question should be edited to include relevant information and then be voted for reopening. Right now we can only guess, since we don't know what's in the original. Certainly it is possible to see _some_ context from a patch, but in this case there seems to be a manipulation of a header field (could even affect the entry point) and then some of whatever that other range points to. 320 == 0x140, could be the `Checksum` field of the optional header in a 64-bit binary, but we don't even know whether this is 64-bit. Besides, in theory the PE header could ...

Comment: ... come way later, since its offset from the file start isn't hardcoded. So a lot of unknown variables here before anyone could attempt a meaningful answer.